# Vim breaking when searching for certain files

Tags: vim, terminal, vim-plugin

I've updated this question to better reflect the situation, when I first posted it I neglected to provide adequate information. Hopefully the following will be sufficient...

> Note: I don't commit my `bundle` folder to GitHub. If you wish to see what plugins I use then refer to this snippet: https://github.com/Integralist/Fresh-Install/blob/master/provision-complete.sh#L28-L70

---

I have a bug in my Vim editor related to the CtrlP plugin. I get an error when searching for a file that doesn't happen all the time (in that, not all patterns I enter cause this error). So it would seem only certain patterns cause the error to appear.

The error is:

```
cgetexpr bm#location_list(). 
E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifable' is off
```

An example pattern that does reproduce the bug is searching for the file "ni_council_map.js".

My Vim and Shell configuration files can be seen here: https://github.com/Integralist/Fresh-Install/tree/master/Shell

Below is a screen shot of the bug happening...

[image]

I've spent a couple of days (on and off) looking at this and haven't been able to nail down where it's coming from. Any ideas on what the cause of the problem is and how I can fix it would be appreciated.

Comment: Your config doesn't seem to have CtrlP or even a bundle directory so we can't see what plugins you have and where that `bm#location_list()` function comes from.

Comment: Probably your repo isn't up to date, because I've tried your config and seems that ctrlP isn't installed but it doesn't show any error

Comment: @romainl please see my update above

Comment: @AlexGuerrero please see my update above

Comment: Only one person downvoted it, don't be so quick to generalize. I didn't downvote it but I'll assume that it's because you didn't demonstrate much willingness to look for the reason yourself. Did you even try to look for `bm#location_list()` in your config or do you expect us to look at those 30+ repos for that function? Also, do you use sessions?

Comment: @romainl You're right in that I should've of spent more time providing better information at the beginning. It was a long day and this was my last ditch effort to find a solution so I'll accept that down vote was my own doing. In answer to your questions: I spent most of the day (and on/off during work hours over the past couple of days) trying to resolve the issue with no luck. I don't use sessions no.

Comment: Well, for the third time, did you grep your config for a `bm#location_list()`?

Comment: Yes I did but it didn't return anything. I also tried Ack'ing the entire folder for that phrase and it didn't return anything either.

Comment: After installing all your plugins if you execute `grep -r "bm#location_list()" it returns some lines from files inside your vim-bookmarks plugin, the -r option is to search files recursively. I've seen that you've found that's the problem is related to this bundle so in my opinion it would be great that you answer your own question to let other users know what fails or update it to try to find a workaround from another user.

Comment: @AlexGuerrero thanks Alex. I'm currently trying to figure out how to fix the vim-bookmarks plugin. Once I do I'll update this question accordingly so others who stumble across it will have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the answer to this question is as follows...

- When pasting from the clipboard into CtrlP, Vim tries to emulate typing... but in NORMAL mode
- I have the vim-bookmarks plugin, that maps `ma` to open a QuickFix window
- So the file name `ni_council_map.js` causes the `ma` part to trigger the QuickFix window
- From there the rest of the file name tries to be executed as a command `p.js`
- That causes the `E21` modifiable error to occur

To fix the issue I either remap `ma` to `<leader>ma` or (more likely) I use CtrlP's built-in feature that handles pasting: `<Ctrl-\>` which lets you select where to paste from (in this case option `c` which is the clipboard option).

It's rare I have this issue with other plugins but it's good to know why it happens and how to resolve it.